# Incorrect values being posted from View after dynamically removing rows

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, http-post

I have the option of dynamically adding and removing rows in my form. Before submitting the form if I remove the last row it works fine but if I remove any other row not in a sequence then add a row and then submit the form it posts the wrong value in my model (i.e. it changes the data of the new row to the data of previous row)

I am using hidden fields but that did not help. The main view renders a partial view which contains the data for the rows. I have tried to use EditorFor but that didn't help either.

Main View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "TimeEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { 
@class= "form-container" }))
{
 <div id="times">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("TimeTable", Model);}    
 </div>
<input name="Submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit" 
id="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

View Model:

```
 public class TimeFilter
{
  public List<TimeItemWeekly> TimeItemWeekly { get; set; }
}

 public class TimeItemWeekly
  {
     public string SelectedJob { get; set; }
     public List<SelectListItem> Job { get; set; }
     public string SelectedServiceItem { get; set; }
     public List<SelectListItem> ServiceItem { get; set; }
   }
```

Partial View:

```
@model NWwebappCS.Models.TimeFilter

@if (Model.TimeItemWeekly != null)
{
for (int i = 0; i < Model.TimeItemWeekly.Count(); i++)
{        
    <div class="row-container @(Model.TimeItemWeekly[i].HasError ? 
        <div class="row">
            <input type="hidden" name="TimeItemWeekly.Index" value="@i" />
            <div class="customer-details">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TimeItemWeekly[i].SelectedJob, 
                Model.TimeItemWeekly[i].Job, new { @class = "jobs select 
                form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="service-details">
                @if (Model.TimeItemWeekly[i].ServiceItem != null)
                {
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => 
                  x.TimeItemWeekly[i].SelectedServiceItem, 
                  Model.TimeItemWeekly[i].ServiceItem, new { @class = 
                  "service-items select" })
                }
                else
                {
                    <select name="TimeItemWeekly[@i].SelectedServiceItem" 
                    class="service-items select">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>
                }
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
}
```

Controller:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Submit(Models.TimeFilter Model, string submit)
    {
       switch (submit)
            {
                case "Submit":
                    string errorMessage = ValidateTime(Model);
                    FillLists(Model);
                    if (errorMessage == "")
                    {
                        DataTable timeRows = GetWeekData(Model);
                        DeleteTime(Model, timeRows);
                        SaveTime(Model, timeRows);
                        if (Model.TimeItemWeekly != null)
                        {
                            Model.TimeItemWeekly = 
                        Model.TimeItemWeekly.OrderBy(x => x.Job.Where(y 
              => 
              y.Selected).First().Text).ThenBy(x => x.ServiceItem.Where(y 
              => y.Selected).First().Text).ToList();
                        }
                        GetUserInfo(Model);
                        HasPrivilege(Model);
                        TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Changes Saved!";
                        return View("~/Views/TimeEntry/Index.cshtml", 
                        Model);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TempData["ErrorMessage"] = errorMessage;
                        return View("~/Views/TimeEntry/Index.cshtml", 
                        Model);
                    }
                default:
                    return View("~/Views/TimeEntry/Index.cshtml", Model);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you removing your rows? Via javascript? You may have to re-index on submit, before post so that the indices are in order with no gaps

Comment: I am using Jquery to remove the rows :                                     `$(document).on("click", ".red-box", function () {
        $(this).closest(".row-container").remove();
    });`

Comment: Well sounds like you either have to loop through your rows and update the `name` values with the correct index (`[i]`) of the new order, or make like an ajax call when you remove one that returns a new Partial view and replace the html with that one in the `#times` div.

Comment: @zgood Thanks! I am quite new at this so I am not sure how to return the new partial view in Ajax call. Would it be somethig like this :  ` $.ajax({
            url: baseURL + "TimeEntry/ChangeCategory/",
            type: "GET",
            data:
            {
               // I am not sure what to add here
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //Fill div with results
                $("#times").html(data);
            }
          });`

Comment: Ya thats the idea, you are very close. You would no longer be removing the row via jQuery. You would still assign a click event to `.red-box`, but it would pass like an id to a controller action that would then handle any logic to "remove" that row. then it would `return PartialView("TimeTable", model);` where the model is a new set of data with the removed row gone. And your ajax succes would be exactly how you have in your comment

Comment: @zgood Thanks! I will give that a try now

Comment: @zgood Thanks a lot ! had spent so much time on it and was not able to figure it out. It works like a charm now!

Comment: good to hear. I will post an answer in a little bit since it worked so maybe it can help someone else in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the indices get out of order and the mvc model binder can't bind the list properly because the `name` values which contain the index position are no longer sequential.

One way to solve this is to create an ajax call that returns your partial view view with an updated data set that doesn't contain the row you removed, and replacing the old partial HTML with a new one that has correct indices.

It would look something like this:

JS event for the remove button:

```
$(document).on("click", ".red-box", function () {
    var id = 1; // this would be the id of the thing you are removing, if needed
    $.get('/path/to/remove', { id: id }, function(data){
       $("#times").html(data);
    }
});
```

Action

```
public ActionResult Remove(int id) {
   // Get data based on id and make any dB updates you need to make

   var model = GetData(); // Get new NWwebappCS.Models.TimeFilter without removed row
   return PartialView("TimeTable", model);
}
```

Something along those lines....